# Defining "non-existent" random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm working on a queueing system with a planned vacation. I explain what that is: the server of the system  (M/G/1) switches from active after some time to inactive. And that repeats after a deterministic cycle time.

Let $p$ be the fraction of the time the server is active. If the service time distribution is exp$(\mu)$ then I would say the density $f$ of the service time distribution is equal to:
\begin{align} 
f(x) = p\mu e^{-\mu x}  + (1-p) h(x) 
\end{align} 
I don't know what $h(x)$ is. Actually there is no service with probability $1-p$ so $h$ is the density of non-existent random variable? I'm very confused about this.

How can one define such things in a proper way? I think there are many things that are going wrong with the way I think.

Comment: What happens to a job that is in service if its server becomes inactive? Does it requeue or exit the system? Does it just wait for the server to come back and continue working on it?

Comment: @David sorry I forgot to mention that, it finishes its service

Comment: What do you mean finished its service? As in, it completes automatically when the server goes on vacation? Or it waits for the server to return, and then completes?

Comment: @David I mean that if it would wait $v$ more minutes if the server would be active, then it waits $v$ more minutes if the server becomes inactive.

Comment: In that case, why isn't the service time distribution simply exponential? Every customer that enters service sees an exponential wait until its service is complete

Comment: @David but customers can not enter while the server is inactive

Comment: Right, but that is an issue of delay not service time.

Comment: @David that is actually right, but can the service time distribution defined in such way that these kind of things is included?

Comment: Not that I know of. It should be incorporated in the sojourn time through the wait time distribution.